# Nodejs ругается на throw

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
try {
    ClientDB.query(querySelectUser, (queryError, queryResponse) => {
        if (queryError) {
            throw new Error('Ошибка сервера');
        }

        if (!queryResponse.rows[0]) throw new Error('ВОТ ТУТ!');

        const passwordDB = queryResponse.rows[0].password;

        if (passwordHash === passwordDB) {
            response
                .status(200);
        } else {
            throw new Error('Не верный пароль');
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
}
```

Node выкидывает ошибку на throw, почему понять не могу. Вставлял в разных участках такое условие. Без условия вставлял, все равно ругается.

```
D:\pets\debtor-back\functions\app\auth\authorization.js:17
                    if (!queryResponse.rows[0]) throw new Error('ВОТ ТУТ!');
                                                ^
```

**Так и не разобрался почему нода ругается. Из комментариев ниже, переделал на промис и вызываю ошибки через reject()**

```
const authorizationQuery = (email, password) => {
  const querySelectUser = `SELECT email, password FROM ${ DB_TABLES.users } WHERE email='${ email }'`;

  return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    ClientDB.query(querySelectUser, (queryError, queryResponse) => {
        if (queryError) return reject(new Error('Ошибка сервера'));
        if (!queryResponse.rows.length) return reject(new Error('Email не зарегестрирован'));

        const user = queryResponse.rows[0];
        if (user.password !== password) return reject(new Error('Пароль не верный'));

        return resolve(user);
      });
  }));
};

const authorization = async (request, response) => {
  const { email, password } = request.body;
  const passwordHash = createSha256(password);
  try {
      const user = await authorizationQuery(email, passwordHash);
      // TODO: добавить генерацию токенов
      response.status(200).json({status: true, data: user});
  } catch (error) {
      response.status(200).json({status: false, title: error.message});
  }
};
```

Comment: А что пишет в ошибке?

Comment: Он не ругается, он указывает на него!

Comment: Если в node.js какая-либо библиотека выдаст какую-нибудь `TypeError`, то ошибка так же будет ссылаться на `throw`

Comment: В ошибке ничего не пишет, просто указывает на throw, причем только в условии `if (!queryResponse.rows[0]) throw new Error('ВОТ ТУТ!')`. В остальных случаях срабатывает

Comment: 1) Если что-то там и ругается то ошибка-то сейчас другая? 2) Какая у вас БД? 3) Какой драйвер используете? 4) queryResponse пробовали хоть раз распечатать? покажите что там

Comment: Переформулируйте свой вопрос относительно новой записи и укажите выбрасываемое исключение, до конца не понятно что у вас происходит, вы ведь код изменили, а ошибка осталась прежняя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myQuery(querySelectUser) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ClientDB.query(querySelectUser, (queryError, queryResponse) => {
            if (queryError) reject('Ошибка сервера');
            if (!queryResponse.rows[0]) reject('ВОТ ТУТ!');

            const passwordDB = queryResponse.rows[0].password;
            if (passwordHash !== passwordDB) reject('Не верный пароль');
            
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        await myQuery({});
        console.log('Данные подтверждены');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Вот явный пример использования `async`/`await` вместе с `try`/`catch`

```js
function myQuery() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) reject('Рандомная ошибка');            

            resolve();
        }, 3000);
    });
}

(async () => {
    try {
        await myQuery();
        console.log('OK');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: const passwordDB = queryResponse.rows[0].password; - выводит ошибку, даже если срабатывают условия выше, перед resolve и reject нужно указывать return, иначе функция не стопится

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вас удивляет, почему не срабатывает `try...catch`, то есть почему ошибка не ловится?

Это потому, что ошибка возникает не в том коде, который вы облекли в `try...catch`, а в колбеке, которые вызывается позже, когда код в `try...catch` уже отработал. Сравните:

```js
try {
  throw new Error();
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Caught 1!'); // Сработает.
}


try {
  setTimeout(() => {
    throw new Error();
  }, 1000);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Caught 2!'); // Не сработает.
}
```

Если вы хотите поймать ошибку в колбеке, вам нужно использовать `try...catch` внутри колбека:

```js
try {
  setTimeout(() => {
    try {
      throw new Error();
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Caught 3!'); // А тут сработает.
    }
  }, 1000);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Caught 2!'); // Не сработает.
}
```

Comment: Эм, да не подумал про асинхронность. Но проблема не в этом, только на `if (!queryResponse.rows[0]) throw new Error('ВОТ ТУТ!')` node в консоли ругается, на всех других throw ошибки нет. Видимо как то связано с условием, но как то это странно для меня